# Symfony DateTimeType without seconds / TimeType for current day

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

For my project I need multiple DateTimeTypes with "special" configuration - but I simply have no idea how to achieve those things (Symfony 5).

**1. DateTimeType without seconds (but still HTML5)**

```
 $builder
    ->add('arrival', DateTimeType::class, ['label' => 'Arrival', 'input' => 'datetime_immutable', 'widget' => 'single_text']);
```

This renders a HTML5 input field with type `datetime-local` which is exactly what I want - except it still has seconds: [image: input with datetime-local]

I want the **:46** removed. This clearly comes from the value option which is automatically(?) set by symfony: [image: value option]

Technically this already works in chrome etc. However this fails the client-side validation in Safari because of the seconds.

*How can I remove the seconds?* The `format` option can not be used (because it requires html5 to be set to false)!

**2. TimeType for the current day**

If you use the TimeType with a `DateTime` object, the date will always be `1970-01-01` which makes total sense - however how can you pre-select the date of the object (e.g. today) and let the user pick the time?

*How can I achieve this?*

Comment: Perhaps this is useful? https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#date-format

Comment: @Simon it is not possible to use the `date_format` option with `html5 = true`. Also I need the seconds removed.

Comment: In Symfony 4.2.8, the code works without seconds. Does it stop working only at Symfony 5? How were you adding a form to the template? form(form)?

Comment: @Clarity oh well, my bad. In the entity I am using the `construct` function to set the default value (today). `$this->arrival = new \DateTimeImmutable();` - I want the current datetime as default

Comment: @Clarity that actually gave me the answer for the both questions - I'll post the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the default value for today, I am using the `construct` method in my entity object.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->arrival = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        $this->departure = \new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }
```

**Answer for Q1:**
In order to remove the seconds, just create a new `DateTime` object without the seconds.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->arrival = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', date('Y-m-d H:i'));
        $this->departure = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', date('Y-m-d H:i'));
    }

    //$this->arrival = new \DateTimeImmutable(date('Y-m-d H:i')); //this also works, but needs execption handling (try/catch)
```

**Answer for Q2:** Same answer for this question - just pre-set the current date in the entity and use the `TimeType` to let the user pick the time.